# Validating String input has no numbers

Tags: java, input, numbers, validation, alphabetical

I have found how to validate that an input is a number using try/catch but how do I go about validating that a user input is alphabetical only and contains no numbers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use a simple regular expression:

```
if (str.matches("[a-zA-Z]+$")) {
   // str consists entirely of letters
}
```

Note that this only works with letters `A-Z` and `a-z`. If you need to properly support Unicode, a better method is to loop over the characters of the string and use [`Character.isLetter()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5,0/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isLetter%28char%29).

Answer (score 2):

```
public static boolean containsNumbers(String str){
    for(char ch : str.toCharArray()){
        if(Character.isDigit(ch)){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

One way is to use regular expressions.

```
private static Pattern p = Pattern.compile("^[A-Za-z]+$");

public static boolean match(String s) {
    return p.matcher(s).matches();
}
```

One other way can be iterate through all characters in your string and check if they are alphabetical or not.